# Do I have to be friends with someone to make them an admin for an app?

Tags: facebook, admin

I'm trying to add someone as an admin to an app I'm working on, but I'm not "friends" with them. When I type their email address in when trying to add them as an admin, it says that user isn't on Facebook. Yet, when I do a search for the user on Facebook using that email address, it finds them instantly.

The only thing I can think of is that this person isn't my friend?

Comment: Yes, you need to be friends with them before you can add them as an admin to an app or page you manage.

Comment: Is that correct? I thought if their privacy settings for being searchable by email allowed finding their name based on their email address, you could add them via email

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you do not need to be friends. Then again the docs may have not been updated to reflect a change in policy.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/development-cycle/

> Users can be added by specifying their name (if they are your friend), email address or Facebook User ID. Users are not required to be friends in order to be added to a Role.

Try their Facebook User ID. If that doesn't work just friend them and try that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this at length. It appears you DO have to be friends with someone on FB to add them as an admin to your app. (Note that this is totally different then adding them as a Page Admin, where apparently you do *not* need to be friends.)

Answer (score -1):

You can just add their email address (but they have to like the page and the email address used needs to be associated with their Facebook account).